# Add tags to "Fitered Questions" SE tab and adjust to match format of other sites

Tags: feature-request, filtering, tag-filters

1. Replace Stats and Top Network Askers with list of tabs from sites subcribed to. Clicking on them should bring up the questions from that tag.
2. Remove boxes around questions.

Now:

[image]

After 1. implemented, clicking on [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas):

[image]

This would make the page more useful and less cluttered.